# Vue Router - get this.$route.query after URL updates from API call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get `this.$route.query` after an API call. Suppose I have a route like this:

`site.com/art-inventory`

And then I do an API call that results in a new URL like this:

`site.com/art-inventory?categories=China&collections=&dateEnd=&dateStart=&favorites=&itemIds=&keyword=&layout=masonry-small&locations=&maxLength=500&maxPrice=5000000&maxWidth=500&merchants=&minLength=0&minPrice=0&minWidth=0&quality=&sublocations=`

Why when I `console.log(this.$route.query)` *after* the API does it still return `{}`?

Do I have to use plain JavaScript to parse the URL? I've tried doing it as a computed prop and still no luck:

`computed: { curQuery() { return this.$route.query },}` // nope

(I should note that if I do a page refresh whilst at the full query URL, then it will return the correct query).

Comment: Could you also include how you redirect and obtain the query after redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and I suspect it is a lifecycle thing.  Normally using `setTimeout` or `this.$nextTick` fixes it.